# Why does Kelly Foster smile by seeing Benjamin vomiting?

Tags: plot-explanation, we-bought-a-zoo

In [*We Bought a Zoo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Bought_a_Zoo), why does Kelly Foster smile by seeing Benjamin vomiting?

[image: Benjamin Vomits]

[image: Kelly Foster smiles]

What is point of this scene?

Answer (score 3):

He's not vomiting...he's trying to catch his breath.

The comment is

> "That is the posture of a quitting man"

He's just been handed a big shock and he's reacting to it....he's angry and frustrated...so much so that he punches the air and kicks over a barrel.

[image]

[image]

### But then...

...he pulls himself together, picks up the kicked over barrel and straightens up.

[image]

Kelly is smiling in realisation that **he hasn't been beaten and isn't giving in"**.

Plus, you know...she "like likes" him. :)